# Getting the highest key from python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a python dictionary with values and I need to search the maximum key.

```
data={'A': 1,'C': 3, 'H': 1,'I': 1, 'B': 1,'J': 2,'S': 1, 'D': 3, 'N': 2}
```

I try `max(data, key=data.get)`.This gives the `C` as an answer.But I'd like to get `C` & `D` as an answer,since both C and D are the highest number.

How this can be done in Python?

Comment: If you said this is duplicated, please show the old ones. Thx

Answer (score 4):

You can not do this with `max` alone, as `max` will only return a single element. Instead, first, get the `max`value from `data`, then filter those keys that have the same value.

```
>>> data={'A': 1, 'T': 1, 'C': 3, 'H': 1, 'I': 1, 'B': 1, 'O': 1,'J': 2, 'Q': 1, 'S': 1, 'D': 3, 'N': 2}
>>> max_val = max(data.values())
>>> [key for key, val in data.items() if val == max_val]
['C', 'D']
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
max_keys = [ k for k, val in data.items() if val == max(data.values()) ]
```

Comment: Here you will evaluate the `max(..)` part **every** time...

Comment: `values()` already returns a list, and as others said, that way you're calculating `max` every loop.

Comment: True, it's better to compute the max value separately and then match directly against that. No specific concern for efficiency was noted though, so I preferred the one-liner version.

Comment: @ChatterOne you're right. For some reason I thought in python 3 values() would give an iterator and I wasn't sure whether max would allow for it. I'll update the answer to remove the useless list(). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create a reverse map.

```
from collections import defaultdict
reverse_data_map = defaultdict(list)

for k, v in data.items():
    reverse_data_map[v].append(k)  # it becomes a list of keys that share a value
```

Then get the highest value, and use it to get your keys.

```
max_keys = reverse_data_map[max(reverse_data_map.keys())]
print max_keys  # ['C', 'D']
```

---

As a robust function:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def get_all_max_keys(d):
    reverse_map = defaultdict(list)
    max_v = 0
    for k, v in d.items():
        max_v = max(max_v, v)  # more efficient method than finding the max afterwards
        reverse_map[v].append(k)
    return reverse_map[max_v]
```

Calling the function:

```
data={
    'A': 1, 'T': 1, 'C': 3, 'H': 1,
    'I': 1, 'B': 1, 'O': 1, 'J': 2,
    'Q': 1, 'S': 1, 'D': 3, 'N': 2,
    }

print get_all_max_keys(data)  # ['C', 'D']
```